# Dynamically created directory returns "Array" 1 in 1000 times

Tags: php, arrays, debugging, dynamic, path

I'm fixing up some old code that is supposed to create a directory for a customer based on the customer's last name. 999 out of 1000 times it works as expected but every now and then I get an "Unable to create base directory" error message and the debug shows me that the `$file_directory` in that case is simply `"Array"` instead of something like `"\\network\path\order_data\1234567890_Smith"`.

Could anyone explain how this code could work the vast majority of the time but still consistently fail about .1% of instances? Or is it something other than the code? Thanks!

***Note: I did not originally write this code but am tring to leave it as close to the original as possible***

***Edit I had a typo in my previous code but I think tliokos and Fluinc had a very good point but just wanted to fix my mistake***

Code:

```
<?php

$file_directory = build_directory($customer, $UID); 

    if(!is_dir($file_directory)){   //Check to make sure it does not already exist
        if(!mkdir($file_directory)){    
            mail("debug@example.com","Unable to create base directory","$file_directory");
        }
    }

function build_directory($customer, $UID){

    if($customer->related_orders){
        $related = explode(",", $customer->related_orders);

        foreach($related as $r_UID){
            $rel_order = get_order($r_UID); //fetches order object

            if((isset($rel_order->file_directory) && $rel_order->file_directory != "")){
                return $rel_order->file_directory;
            }
        }
    }

//Here is where I made my correction
        $paths = array('\\\\network\\path');
        $base = $paths[0];


        //Test if directory is already assigned
        if(is_dir($base . "\\order_data\\".$UID."_".str_replace(" ","_",$customer->last_name)."\\")){ 
            return $base . "\\order_data\\".$UID."_".str_replace(" ","_",$customer->last_name)."\\";
        }

        if($base){
            return $base . "\\order_data\\".$UID."_".str_replace(" ","_",$customer->last_name)."\\";
        }

    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem ended up being framework/user related.
We discovered that if the user refreshed the page during the directory creation it would create the same directory twice which our framework would save as an array of identical paths.

Answer (score 1):

Change $base = array('\\network\path');
To $base = '\\network\path';

Comment: I found a typo in my code when I copied it over, I think you could still have a point but just wanted to point out and correct my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the build_directory() function and more specifically after the first if.

So if the customer has no related orders, you are trying to concatenate an Array with a string and the result is like

```
Array\order_data\....
```

Try o change

`$base = array('\\network\path');`

to

```
$base = '\\network\path';
```

Comment: That does make a lot of sense, but why would that make it fail every once in a while?

Comment: I found a typo in my code when I copied it over, I think you could still have a point but just wanted to point out and correct my mistake.